# Vega custom tooltip data visualisation

Tags: visualization, vega

Could anyone help be to develop a tooltip at line chart that looks like this?

[image: expected behaviour]

Here is my spec at [Vega Lite Editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/?#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-Dt2-P9a2o64s2A0DwPndjl1g1d8HXRDvT4vdJQw6TsKvIyhJhCTn0E99ZMogCAzoqQW0YlTWLgKCOLg7SEM3cgiR3Az0OsvyTNwkjE0IySzIi8i5PTEcGxwcxHJwbNW1JVyIPc9SYO7PBvJ4oc1RQwLor7ZERLK8SiKqmFbPk0cmxSol0qnZiwLcjyNLy7jdMo4r+MM4LQqk0j-Ms0b+tiuyEpxccksnABVTAAGtMHQIRsG6zi3AAvEUrNHM8GWtaNq23KdrwADaIJEUjpAE71s2zzVwAo0UrSkNHrOl6uPswMltWp7zpXP7ZszZrAdO57trggCmoJT63G+mGLrh+IlmmGAyGgdYQGcKYzmXCYph8DxAnc-M3BEMQJGWBpd2wHBQBWEhtmIXZXEEXIaTANwzhiBKCbcS5icmNxImY0pBEplJOmUNRoMwBAYHCFA4QgQRui8dBcHVsJ6acRncBZ1Z2c5wIedIPm8EuQX62FvAilIEo7RJtwSmMaxfll8I7BAABiH8AEE5EoABRQIA7NGBsgADm0KOYDAaQYE0bIQAScAGeYE3wDNvAdj2bmKmtwpYkx4gTlxzJQHKSo3FqFB6kaCxsb2PABfrev6AliActgHGRdiLOikwXJTGZ6YUEGDvQBUeFIAAWj8aoiyn7I+iRBBtakBzcnyNwA5gE-T8tvoAHUFfUXA4-ke2QCrhE85URAbf1zWQFf0RqBd0o8ADlcIBwCK6CCNnAFaxxQAz3FngV+tAgTczgA0PO2RjwQCqBsLYeAXiIFxssAufwObFy-sgy81QCStgfuAyBeMYFTElpbZBjQp6szWDgrwFRbB1hAKkIokA86VC8HnHEoBB4dwbCXXm-NMQpTEe3KYoscilxto5HhUB1boBWuEeRQ8nbFGlso6RTtZEaOQdoi+ohxB5wOGEfkD9Lysx0e4egXgfB+ACFPSwKhvZuA8G43w-hFgWE0dogA8gYGACAZ42NCOESQD8uhBGEV40JEAInHmiQSUAtjwiyB4NoQW9toHuxwcMUYTCUGsMIbgrhsi+HoAEVPRxQSRF53EYTS2KiZE8OyVjPRjkpFl1trIg+pAMlRJiVPXJ5xEnoGSf-UAYyJlZNiYceJPCxntIUYUAxXTjFUOJLOKArtplxLcGTVxpQeGg3aVYMgbhgAAHI0AoCSE8yErMaBOB4DANUTzyAfPIF8n5oMYgV0FnEDGQA).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tooltips work on key:value pairs. If you amend your input data to an object of key value pairs and create a flatten transform, you can achieve your desired behaviour. I have changed all the tooltips below to be identical for speed but you should see the pattern.

[image]

```
{
  "description": "Total Count line chart.",
  "width": 1200,
  "height": 450,
  "padding": 5,
  "signals": [{"name": "interpolate", "value": "linear"}],
  "legends": [
    {
      "fill": "color",
      "orient": "bottom",
      "direction": "horizontal",
      "symbolType": "square"
    }
  ],
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "table",
      "values": [
        {
          "x": 0,
          "y": 30,
          "c": "Passenger Vessel",
          "tooltip": [
            {
              "title": "My Title",
              "Tall Ship": 0,
              "Sailing Yacht": 10,
              "Super Yacht": 20,
              "Motor Yacht": 10,
              "Rib": 0
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "x": 1,
          "y": 20,
          "c": "Passenger Vessel",
          "tooltip": [
            {
              "title": "My Title",
              "Tall Ship": 0,
              "Sailing Yacht": 10,
              "Super Yacht": 20,
              "Motor Yacht": 10,
              "Rib": 0
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "x": 2,
          "y": 90,
          "c": "Passenger Vessel",
          "tooltip": [
            {
              "Tall Ship": 0,
              "Sailing Yacht": 10,
              "Super Yacht": 20,
              "Motor Yacht": 10,
              "Rib": 0
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "x": 3,
          "y": 60,
          "c": "Passenger Vessel",
          "tooltip": [
            {
              "title": "My Title",
              "Tall Ship": 0,
              "Sailing Yacht": 10,
              "Super Yacht": 20,
              "Motor Yacht": 10,
              "Rib": 0
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "x": 4,
          "y": 50,
          "c": "Passenger Vessel",
          "tooltip": [
            {
              "title": "My Title",
              "Tall Ship": 0,
              "Sailing Yacht": 10,
              "Super Yacht": 20,
              "Motor Yacht": 10,
              "Rib": 0
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "x": 5,
          "y": 40,
          "c": "Passenger Vessel",
          "tooltip": [
            {
              "title": "My Title",
              "Tall Ship": 0,
              "Sailing Yacht": 10,
              "Super Yacht": 20,
              "Motor Yacht": 10,
              "Rib": 0
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "x": 6,
          "y": 10,
          "c": "Passenger Vessel",
          "tooltip": [
            {
              "title": "My Title",
              "Tall Ship": 0,
              "Sailing Yacht": 10,
              "Super Yacht": 20,
              "Motor Yacht": 10,
              "Rib": 0
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "x": 0,
          "y": 50,
          "c": "Pleasure Craft",
          "tooltip": [
            {
              "title": "My Title",
              "Tall Ship": 0,
              "Sailing Yacht": 10,
              "Super Yacht": 20,
              "Motor Yacht": 10,
              "Rib": 0
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "x": 1,
          "y": 10,
          "c": "Pleasure Craft",
          "tooltip": [
            {
              "title": "My Title",
              "Tall Ship": 0,
              "Sailing Yacht": 10,
              "Super Yacht": 20,
              "Motor Yacht": 10,
              "Rib": 0
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "x": 2,
          "y": 50,
          "c": "Pleasure Craft",
          "tooltip": [
            {
              "Tall Ship": 0,
              "Sailing Yacht": 10,
              "Super Yacht": 20,
              "Motor Yacht": 10,
              "Rib": 0
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "x": 3,
          "y": 40,
          "c": "Pleasure Craft",
          "tooltip": [
            {
              "title": "My Title",
              "Tall Ship": 0,
              "Sailing Yacht": 10,
              "Super Yacht": 20,
              "Motor Yacht": 10,
              "Rib": 0
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "x": 4,
          "y": 110,
          "c": "Pleasure Craft",
          "tooltip": [
            {
              "title": "My Title",
              "Tall Ship": 0,
              "Sailing Yacht": 10,
              "Super Yacht": 20,
              "Motor Yacht": 10,
              "Rib": 0
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "x": 5,
          "y": 40,
          "c": "Pleasure Craft",
          "tooltip": [
            {
              "title": "My Title",
              "Tall Ship": 0,
              "Sailing Yacht": 10,
              "Super Yacht": 20,
              "Motor Yacht": 10,
              "Rib": 0
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "x": 6,
          "y": 20,
          "c": "Pleasure Craft",
          "tooltip": [
            {
              "title": "My Title",
              "Tall Ship": 0,
              "Sailing Yacht": 10,
              "Super Yacht": 20,
              "Motor Yacht": 10,
              "Rib": 0
            }
          ]
        },
        {"x": 0, "y": 50, "c": "Unknown", "tooltip": [{}]},
        {"x": 1, "y": 60, "c": "Unknown", "tooltip": [{}]},
        {"x": 2, "y": 90, "c": "Unknown", "tooltip": [{}]},
        {"x": 3, "y": 40, "c": "Unknown", "tooltip": [{}]},
        {"x": 4, "y": 50, "c": "Unknown", "tooltip": [{}]},
        {"x": 5, "y": 20, "c": "Unknown", "tooltip": [{}]},
        {"x": 6, "y": 40, "c": "Unknown", "tooltip": [{}]}
      ],
      "transform": [{"type": "flatten", "fields": ["tooltip"]}]
    }
  ],
  "scales": [
    {
      "name": "x",
      "type": "point",
      "range": "width",
      "domain": {"data": "table", "field": "x"}
    },
    {
      "name": "y",
      "type": "linear",
      "range": "height",
      "nice": true,
      "zero": true,
      "domain": {"data": "table", "field": "y"}
    },
    {
      "name": "color",
      "type": "ordinal",
      "range": ["#BA20CE", "#60cf85", "#cd2c4f"],
      "domain": {"data": "table", "field": "c"}
    }
  ],
  "axes": [
    {"orient": "bottom", "scale": "x"},
    {"orient": "left", "scale": "y"}
  ],
  "config": {
    "style": {
      "guide-label": {"fontSize": 14, "fill": "#cccccc", "fontWeight": 800}
    },
    "axis": {"grid": true, "gridColor": "#333333"}
  },
  "marks": [
    {
      "type": "group",
      "from": {"facet": {"name": "series", "data": "table", "groupby": "c"}},
      "marks": [
        {
          "type": "line",
          "from": {"data": "series"},
          "encode": {
            "enter": {
              "x": {"scale": "x", "field": "x"},
              "y": {"scale": "y", "field": "y"},
              "stroke": {"scale": "color", "field": "c"},
              "strokeWidth": {"value": 2}
            },
            "update": {
              "interpolate": {"signal": "interpolate"},
              "strokeOpacity": {"value": 1}
            },
            "hover": {"strokeOpacity": {"value": 0.5}}
          }
        },
        {
          "type": "symbol",
          "from": {"data": "series"},
          "encode": {
            "update": {
              "x": {"scale": "x", "field": "x"},
              "y": {"scale": "y", "field": "y"},
              "fillOpacity": {"value": 0}
            },
            "hover": {
              "fillOpacity": {"value": 1},
              "fill": {"scale": "color", "field": "c"},
              "cursor": {"value": "pointer"},
              "tooltip": {"signal": "datum['tooltip'] "}
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: hello! Is there any option to add a title at tooltip together with `datum['tooltip']`?

Comment: Yes. I'll update my answer.